# jQuery ListView autodividers add id to each section

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i'm using jQuery ListView to display a list with names of customers grouped by the first character,
Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
  <h2>My Phonebook</h2>
  <ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-inset="true">
    <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Albert</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cameron</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Chloe</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Diana</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gabriel</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Glen</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ralph</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Valarie</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

i would like to be able to navigate to each of these sections, however this method doesn't add automatically a id to each section, is it possible to add a id programmatically to each section (like id=a, id=g etc.) ?

Comment: what is the problem in adding manually

Comment: the data-role="listview" method adds programmatically elements on the page which i don't see at the design time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this below jquery code but before give some id for **`ul`** (here i gave "list_ul")

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-inset="true" id="list_ui">
```

code:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#pageone", function( event ) {
    var arr1 = [];
    $("#list_ul").find('.ui-li-divider').each(function() {
        arr1.push($( this ).text());
    });
    var i=0;
    $('.ui-li-divider').each(function() {
        $( this ).attr( "id",arr1[i++]);
    });
    return false;   
});
```